# spring junit runner load context configuraiton one time for multi test case

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc, junit

I have one scenario,

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:integration-test.xml"})
public abstract class IntegrationTestBase
```

each new integration test will extend this class, I would like to let spring unit test runner only load it once, how can do it?

actually there are embeded active mq in integration-test.xml, but when there is test fail, the

activeMQ will be re-initialized agian.

Comment: By default it is already cached by the test context framework. This will only work if every test runs in the same JVM if not it will be loaded for each test again. This is due to the fact that caching is done in a static variable in the test context framework.

Comment: actually there are embeded active mq in integration-test.xml, but when there is test fail, the 

activeMQ will be re-initialized agian. so i think it is not load only once.

Comment: Trust me it is unless you are doing something explicit or marking it dirty or not running the tests in the same jvm it is cached. That is the default of the Spring TestContext framework. If your tests add additional files to load it will not be cached as each full context is cached based on a key calculated from the locations attribute.